# Safe navigation operator (&.) for nil

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.3, safe-navigation-operator

As Ruby 2.3 introduces the Safe navigation operator(`&.`), a.k.a lonely operator, the behavior on `nil` object seems odd.

```
nil.nil?    # => true
nil&.nil?   # => nil
```

Is that designed to behave like this way? Or some edge case that slipped away when adding the lonely operator?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`foo&.bar` is shorthand for `foo && foo.bar`, so what would you expect the result of the expression `nil && nil.nil?` to be?

Answer (score 8):

This is because `nil&.nil?` is shorthand for `nil && nil.nil?`.  This would evaluate to `nil && true`, which is then `nil`.

`(nil && x).nil?` always evaluates to `true`, for any value of `x`.

While the syntax has power, this specific case has some potential to become a 'gotcha' for a developer:

`(stuff&.things).nil?` => This produces `true` if stuff doesn't exist, or `stuff.things` returns `nil`.

vs. the below case:

`stuff&.things&.nil?` => This produces `nil` in every case except the case where `stuff.things` returns something other than `nil`, in which case it would return `false`.

Because of the difficulty in normal boolean logic of differentiating between `false` and `nil`, it is unlikely that this would make sense in normal logic.

Answer (score 0):

`safe navigation operator:` tells Ruby to only call the next method if the receiver isn’t nil. Otherwise, the expression returns nil.

class Roster
attr_accessor :players
end

```
class Player
  attr_accessor :name, :position
  
  def initialize(name, position)
    @name = name
    @position = position
  end

end
```

With these two objects, we can create a roster for a 2-on-2 women’s basketball tournament:

```
moore = Player.new("Maya Moore", "Forward")
taurasi = Player.new("Diana Taurasi", "Guard")
tourney_roster1 = Roster.new
tourney_roster1.players = [moore, taurasi]
```

If we want to know the forward for our 2-on-2 team, we might find the name this way:

```
if tourney_roster1.players.first.position == "Forward"
  puts "Forward: #{tourney_roster1.players.first.name}"
end
```

But what if our opposing roster isn’t set correctly?

```
tourney_roster2 = Roster.new
if tourney_roster2.players.first.position == "Forward"
  puts "Forward: #{tourney_roster1.players.first.name}"
end
```

tourney_roster2 hasn’t yet been set with any players. The preceding code will raise a NoMethodError because tourney_roster2.players returns nil. We can add conditional statements to avoid this, but it makes our if statement verbose and unclear:

```
if tourney_roster2.players &&
   tourney_roster2.players.first &&
   tourney_roster2.players.first.position == "Forward"
```

Instead, we can use the safe navigation operator to avoid the NoMethodError:

```
if tourney_roster2.players&.first&.position == "Forward"
  puts "Forward: #{tourney_roster1.players.first.name}"
end
```

**Some legitimate use cases:** The safe navigation operator comes in handy when working with multiple objects, as shown here, and when chaining methods together.