# What is the pre-Ruby2.3 equivalent to the safe navigation operator (&. or "ampersand-dot")?

Tags: ruby, null, operators, ruby-2.3, safe-navigation-operator

The answers to every question I can find ([Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583168/safe-navigation-operator-for-nil), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164004/does-ruby-have-syntax-for-safe-navigation-operator-of-nil-values-like-in-groovy)) regarding Ruby's new safe navigation operator (`&.`) wrongly declare that `obj&.foo` is equivalent to `obj && obj.foo`.

It's easy to demonstrate that this equivalence is incorrect:

```
obj = false
obj && obj.foo  # => false
obj&.foo        # => NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for false:FalseClass
```

Further, there is the problem of multiple evaluation. Replacing `obj` with an expression having side effects shows that the side effects are doubled only in the `&&` expression:

```
def inc() @x += 1 end

@x = 0
inc && inc.itself  # => 2

@x = 0
inc&.itself        # => 1
```

What is the most concise pre-2.3 equivalent to `obj&.foo` that avoids these issues?

Comment: I don't think there is a pre-2.3 equivalent. That's why they added it.

Comment: But considering that Rails `try` method seems to function like the `&` I would guess they implemented very similarly: `inc.try(:itself) #=> 1`. You can view the `try` source here https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/be589a8b01500a4b52a86248458bf57597e568e8/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb#L62

Comment: @Mike I was able to come up with `(x = inc; x.itself unless x.nil?)` as a pre-2.3 equivalent. I'm hoping there's something less verbose. ActiveSupport's `try` may end up replicating a lot of the `&.` functionality, but it's not a direct equivalent.

Comment: `&.` is not equivalent to `obj && obj.foo`, but in most cases it is.
_u&.profile reminds us as short form of u && u.profile._ says Matz in https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537#note-42.

Answer (score 1):

The safe navigation operator in Ruby 2.3 works almost exactly the same as the [`try!`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/be589a8b01500a4b52a86248458bf57597e568e8/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb#L69-L80) method added by ActiveSupport, minus its block handling.

A simplified version of that could look like this:

```
class Object
  def try(method, *args, &block)
    return nil if self.nil?
    public_send(method, *args, &block)
  end
end
```

You can use this like

```
obj.try(:foo).try(:each){|i| puts i}
```

This `try` method implements various details of the safe navigation operator, including:

- It always returns `nil` if the receiver is `nil`, regardless of whether `nil` actually implements the queried method or not.
- It raises a `NoMethodError` if the non-`nil` receiver doesn't support the method.
- It doesn't swallow any exceptions on method calls.

Due to differences in language semantics, it can not (fully) implement other features of the real safe navigation operator, including:

- Our `try` method always evaluates additional arguments, in contrast to the safe navigation operator. Consider this example

  ```
  nil&.foo(bar())
  ```

  Here, `bar()` is not evaluated. When using our `try` method as

  ```
  nil.try(:foo, bar())
  ```

  we always call the `bar` method first, regardless of whether we later call `foo` with it or not.
- `obj&.attr += 1` is valid syntax in Ruby 2.3.0 which can not be emulated with just a single method call in previous language versions.

Note that when actually implementing this code in production, you should have a look at [Refinements](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) instead of patching core classes.

Comment: What do you mean, *minus its block handling*?

Comment: Well, you can call ActiveSupport's `try!` method with a block (and no other arguments) and it will yield to the block unless the receiver is `nil`. This is not possible with the the safe navigation operator. See the (above linked) [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/be589a8b01500a4b52a86248458bf57597e568e8/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb#L69-L80) for details.

Comment: Your code does not handle `try(:nil?)` on `nil` as pointed out in Jesse Sielaff's comment above. 

`a = nil; a.try(:nil?) #=> nil`

Comment: Which is exactly what the safe navigation operator does. `nil&.nil?` returns `nil` in Ruby 2.3.0.

Comment: You are correct, however that behaviour is extremely surprising. So in versions lower than ruby 2.3, `nil.to_i #=> 0` and with the safe operator `nil&.to_i #=> nil`.

So even methods that `nil` understands are just thrown away and `nil` is returned instead of actually calling the method... TIL

Comment: Your answer makes an excellent point about `bar` never being evaluated in the `&.` expression versus being evaluated in the regular `.` expression. I hadn't considered that feature.

Comment: I don't think it's true that the `&.`...`+=` functionality can't be emulated in pre-2.3 Ruby. The "macro"-like substitution I came up with above, `(x = {{receiver expression}}; x.{{method call}} unless x.nil?)` is perfectly capable of emulating it.

Comment: I edited the sentence to be more precise. Basically, what you would have to do is to check the receiver and then call `attr` and `attr=` only if it is not `nil`. As these two method calls are independent of each other (i.e. the receiver `obj)` can't know it is called with a `+=` operator, you can't handle it in a single `try` call.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most similar method that the safe traversal operators emulate is Rails' `try` method. However not exactly, we need to handle the case when the object is not `nil` but also does not respond to the method.

Which will return nil if the method can not evaluate the given method.

We can rewrite `try` pretty simply by:

```
class Object
  def try(method)
    if !self.respond_to?(method) && !self.nil?
      raise NoMethodError, "undefined method #{ method } for #{ self.class }"
    else
      begin
        self.public_send(method) 
      rescue NoMethodError
        nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then it can be used in much the same way:

Ruby 2.2 and lower:

```
a = nil
a.try(:foo).try(:bar).try(:baz)
# => nil

a = false
a.try(:foo)
# => NoMethodError: undefined method :foo for FalseClass
```

Equivalent in Ruby 2.3

```
a = nil
a&.foo&.bar&.baz
# => nil

a = false
a&.foo
# => NoMethodError
```

Comment: Admittedly, this is the height of nitpicking, but I'm not sure this is an exact equivalent. Given `obj = nil`, I get `obj&.foo&.nil? # => nil` and `obj.try(:foo).try(:nil?) # => true`.

Comment: Interesting observation. I'll admit that I'm stumped. It might be the case that an intermediary "`nil` but not really `nil`" value is returned via the safe traversal operator that the above definition of `try` does not do.

Comment: (1) You swallow exceptions on `public_send` and (2) you don't return `nil` on any method calls on `nil` itself, both of which deviate from the behavior of the safe navigation operator.

Comment: 1) You do not swallow exceptions. The difference between `send` and `public_send` is that `public_send` only calls public methods. If the method does not exist, it still raises a `NoMethodError`, and if the method does exist and errors, so will the code.

2) The `nil` point is valid but as discussed above, would require a different return type other than `nil` to behave EXACTLY like the safe navigation operator.

Comment: @yez `self.public_send(method) rescue nil` swallows any exception which might be raised, including the `NoMethodError`, regardless of whether you use `send` or `public_send` here. Also, you don't need "another" nil. If the receiver is `nil`, the safe navigation operator *always* returns `nil`. The same nil that is used everywhere else in Ruby.

Comment: A final point which was not covered yet in your code is that objects are not required to signal if they respond to a message in their `respond_to?`. It is certainly a good idea to do so but not required. If you e.g. simply overwrite `method_missing` without also specifying `respond_to_missing?`, you can still handle the method call normally, including by using the safe navigation operator. Your code raises a `NoMethodError` instead.

Comment: 1. Yes the rescue gets rid of exceptions, not the `public_send` as your first comment indicated. 

2. This code does not handle the case where someone defined `method_missing` and not `respond_to` but it also doesn't handle code that changes itself dynamically every single invocation, because who would be crazy enough to do that?