# Why do I get "undefined method for nil:NilClass" on an object that clearly exists?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

controller

```
def show
  @dailies = Daily.where(store_id: params[:store]).order(created_at: :asc).by_month_year(params[:month],params[:year])
  @services = Service.all.order(id: :asc)
end
```

view

```
<%= daily_data_for(params[:store], params[:month], date.day, params[:year], 'starting_safe') %>
```

helper

```
def daily_data_for(store, month, day, year, field)
  Daily.where(store_id: store, month: month, day: day, year: year).first().send(field)
end
```

I'm getting the error `undefined method 'starting_safe' for nil:NilClass` when trying to display ActiveRecord object attribute in the view. I'm a but confused as it shouldn't be nil, because if I remove .send(field) from the helper, I get `#<Daily:0x00007fea597aad50>`. So it's returning an object. So then I inspect the Activerecord Object in the view:

```
daily_data_for(params[:store], params[:month], date.day, params[:year], 'starting_safe').inspect
```

Which displays `#<Daily id: 1030, store_id: 1, created_at: "2018-10-01 18:20:07", updated_at: "2018-10-01 18:20:07", starting_safe: 0.1e1, ending_safe: 0.1e1, total_in: 0.1e1, total_out: 0.1e1, sum: 0.1e1, starting_drawer: 0.1e1, ending_drawer: 0.1e1, over_short: 0.1e1, year: "2018", month: "10", day: "1">`

It's getting the right record and returning it, but then I get undefined method of nil class when I try to access starting_safe.

Why am I unable to display starting_safe in the view? I'd like to be using the instance variable @dailies in the helper instead of querying the database again, but I get the same errors. I've tried in the console and everything works fine. I'm a bit lost as to what's going on here.

Comment: Do you call this method in a loop?

Comment: It's within a loop from a helper method for grabbing the date for each day in a month

Comment: No need to copy answers into your post. Instead, simply mark the answer as accepted and optionally comment on it.

Comment: Just curious, what is the purpose of the view code you've posted?  It seems to be complex logic in the view.

Comment: To add to @Sergio's comment, you are most welcome to post your own answers. Just make sure you post them as an answer below, and not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the record you inspect (Daily with id=1030) and the failing [non-existing] record are two different records. Here's how you can find out. Amend your method like this, temporarily:

```
def daily_data_for(store, month, day, year, field)
  daily = Daily.where(store_id: store, month: month, day: day, year: year).first
  raise "Daily not found for #{store.inspect}, #{month.inspect}, #{day.inspect}, #{year.inspect}" unless daily
  daily.send(field)
end
```

Now the error message should be much more revealing.

Comment: It's returning `0.1e1` which is the value of the starting_safe, and all of the other attributes are also now being displayed. Can you explain why that worked?? Whoops, i had .inspect in the view still. It properly displays `1.0` now.

Comment: @DavidS Did it work, though? it simply ignored the error. Have you checked the logs to see which parameters were logged? Also check out my second variant. The error will be in your face, won't miss it :)

Comment: @DavidS This is currently not really a fix. More something to find your missing record. It should be printed in the server log. The *NoMethodError* exception is still raised, but caught printing out the input values that caused the exception and returning `nil`. If you'd like to return `nil` if no object is found save it into a variable and call *send* only if it contains an object. `daily = Daily.find_by(store_id: store, month: month, day: day, year, year) or return`.

Comment: Adding the rescue line 'fixes' it. I'll have to dig around more and see if I can figure out what exactly happened. I'm still a bit new to rails/ruby, so I'm still learning how to properly debug.

Comment: @JohanWentholt: removed that rescue/log snippet in favor of the more foolproof one

Comment: @DavidS: it wasn't meant to be a fix. It's a debugging measure. Don't leave it there. Try the current snippet

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It was fine, but should `raise` without arguments inside the rescue block to re-raise the current exception after printing your custom message.

Comment: `find_by` is a bit cleaner in my opinion so that one does not miss the `first` at the end. @JohanWentholt `or return` is dirty to me; given the rails version `find_by(...)&.send(field)` is less of an antipattern

Comment: @DavidS it is just a guess that as you probably loop thru each day of the month, for some day you have zero records, hence first() returns nil and then the error is raised.

Comment: @engineersmnky `send` is dirty too. For active records there's 
 cleaner `read_attribute(field)` :)

Comment: @engineersmnky I agree with you that using the safe navigator is better here, since the only thing to do after finding the record is sending the method name. However I don't consider `or return` dirty. `or` and `and` are fine for use in flow control. As long as you don't use them in boolean context. https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide/pull/730

Comment: @SergioTulentsev very nice (I was unaware of that method) as long as it is a true `attribute` which in this case it definitely appears to be

Comment: @MihailPanayotov I believe that was the issue. Thank you everyone that was involved. You've all contributed valuable tips!

Comment: @johanwentholt I have a general distaste for early returns (excepting guard clauses)  but that's just my opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

The error `undefined method 'starting_safe' for nil:NilClass` is specifically telling you that you can't call `starting_safe` on `nil`.  Since your helper method calls a scope `.where` method, calling `.first` on that doesn't insure that it won't be an empty activerecord relation object. If it is empty, then calling `.first` on it will return `nil`.  So you might wanna just use [safe navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583168/safe-navigation-operator-for-nil) to be safe.

```
def daily_data_for(store, month, day, year, field)
  Daily.where(store_id: store, month: month, day: day, year: year).first&.send(field)
end
```

Or if you happen to be on ruby version < 2.3 just use a `.try`

```
Daily.where(store_id: store, month: month, day: day, year: year).first.try(:send, field)
#try will only run if first is not nil
```

Comment: Good tips, but, of course, if they expect/allow records to be missing. Sometimes missing record is a legitimate failure state (and so the app should crash loudly)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes agreed. However, the OP asked WHY they were getting the error.  I suppose I didn't need to explain how they might fix it. However, IMHO the method's use in the view doesn't make much sense here.

Comment: The method call in the view looks fine to me. Not any more complex than, say, `options_for_select`. The N+1 is the real problem here.