# Can I query against the DEVISE current_user helper in my application menu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

The problem is, In the menu of my app I want to check if the current user has a book. If they do I will show a link to the edit book path, if not, I will show a link to the create book path.

```
<% if current_user.book? %>
<% else %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to access `current_user` from any controller.  But always make sure you handle if `current_user` returns `nil`.
You can use a try or [safe navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583168/safe-navigation-operator-for-nil).

```
<% if current_user.try(:book?) %>
<% else %>
<% end %>
```

Or

```
<% if current_user&.book? %>
<% else %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried your answer and it seems to only show the code thats in the ELSE section regardless of whether of not the user has a book. Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't say why unless you're sure `.book?` returns true, which defies the logic here. If you use `pry` or `bye-bug` or any such debugging tool, try to add one right before this line of code and make sure your expectations are correct.